# Как вывести несколько элементов одного словаря, не переписывая полный путь к нему?

Tags: python-3.x, json, list, словари, вывод

Есть участок кода, который получает огромный массив данных с сервера в формате json. Данные в нём устроены таким образом, что для получения данных относительно одного элемента(к примеру относительно элемента с идентификатором **0**) нужно прописать огромный путь к ним. Данных много, путь длинный. Вот этот код:

```py
response2 = requests.get(csourl)
todos2 = json.loads(response2.text)
print(todos2 == response2.json()) # True
print(type(todos2)) # <class 'dict'>
print(todos2['response'][0]['id'], todos2['response'][0]['name'], todos2['response'][0]['ip'], todos2['response'][0]['city'], todos2['response'][0]['time'], todos2['response'][0]['status'], todos2['response'][0]['sex'], todos2['response'][0]['ident'] )
```

Есть ли возможность сократить запись таким образом, что бы в приведённом участке кода не повторять много раз **todos2['response'][0]['разнообразные данные']**.

P.S.Путь к **разнообразным данным** в другой моей работе намного больше, чем я прописал здесь. Надеюсь суть задачи ясна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял:

```
print('Пример: 1')
data1 = {
    'response': [
        {'id': {'длинный': {'путь': 'данные 0'}}},
        {'id': {'длинный': {'путь': 'данные 1'}}},
        {'id': {'длинный': {'путь': 'данные 2'}}},
    ]}

print('Способ 1:', *[i['id']['длинный']['путь'] for i in data1['response']])

def get(item):
    return item['id']['длинный']['путь']

print('Способ 2:', *[get(i) for i in data1['response']])

print('Пример: 2')
from operator import iconcat
from functools import reduce
data1 = {
    'response': [
        {'id': {'разный1': {'путь': 'данные 0_1'},
                'разный2': {'путь': 'данные 0_2'},
                'разный3': {'путь': 'данные 0_3'},
               }},
        {'id': {'разный1': {'путь': 'данные 1_1'},
                'разный2': {'путь': 'данные 1_2'},
                'разный3': {'путь': 'данные 1_3'},
               }},
        {'id': {'разный1': {'путь': 'данные 2_1'},
                'разный2': {'путь': 'данные 2_2'},
                'разный3': {'путь': 'данные 2_3'},
               }},
    ]}

print('Способ 1:', *[sub['id'][k]['путь']
                     for sub in data1['response']
                     for k in sub['id'].keys()])

def get(item):
    return [item['id'][k]['путь'] for k in item['id'].keys()]

print('Способ 2:', *reduce(iconcat, [get(i) for i in data1['response']]))

print('Пример: 3')
data1 = {
    'response': {
        'id': {'разный1': 'данные 1',
               'разный2': 'данные 2',
               'разный3': 'данные 3',
              }}}

tmp = data1['response']['id']
print('Способ 1:', tmp['разный1'], tmp['разный2'], tmp['разный3'])
print('Способ 2:', *[v for v in tmp.values()])
```

Результат:

```
Пример: 1
Способ 1: данные 0 данные 1 данные 2
Способ 2: данные 0 данные 1 данные 2
Пример: 2
Способ 1: данные 0_1 данные 0_2 данные 0_3 данные 1_1 данные 1_2 данные 1_3 данные 2_1 данные 2_2 данные 2_3
Способ 2: данные 0_1 данные 0_2 данные 0_3 данные 1_1 данные 1_2 данные 1_3 данные 2_1 данные 2_2 данные 2_3
Пример: 3
Способ 1: данные 1 данные 2 данные 3
Способ 2: данные 1 данные 2 данные 3
```