# Выборка данных из вложенного словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, tuple

Есть файл `json`. Мне необходимо забрать из него все записи по ключу `vintage` и значению `name`. Перепробовал все возможные способы, но не могу понять, как правильно это сделать?

Вот пример файла:

```
{
  "explore_vintage": {
    "market": {
      "country": "ru",
      "currency": {
        "code": "RUB",
        "name": "Russian Rouble",
        "prefix": null,
        "suffix": "₽"
      }
    },
    "records_matched": 9114,
    "matches": [
      {
        "vintage": {
          "id": 156240236,
          "seo_name": "kvareli-akhasheni-red-akhasheni-krasnoe-kakheti-2013",
          "name": "Kvareli Akhasheni Red (Ахашени Красное) 2013",
          "statistics": {
            "status": "Normal",
            "ratings_count": 37,
            "ratings_average": 4.6,
            "labels_count": 409
          },
          "image": {
            "location": "//images.vivino.com/labels/M-DRD7hCQfK60EBrmnbXYA.jpg",
            "variations": {
              "large": "//images.vivino.com/thumbs/M-DRD7hCQfK60EBrmnbXYA_375x500.jpg",
              "medium": "//images.vivino.com/thumbs/M-DRD7hCQfK60EBrmnbXYA_150x200.jpg",
              "medium_square": "//images.vivino.com/thumbs/M-DRD7hCQfK60EBrmnbXYA_150x150.jpg",
              "small_square": "//images.vivino.com/thumbs/M-DRD7hCQfK60EBrmnbXYA_80x80.jpg"
            }
```

Comment: Ответ на аналогичный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1002341/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc/1002362#1002362

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['explore_vintage']['matches'])
```

результат:

```
In [44]: df
Out[44]:
   vintage.id                   vintage.image.location           vintage.image.variations.large  \
0   156240236  //images.vivino.com/labels/M-DRD7hCQ...  //images.vivino.com/thumbs/M-DRD7hCQ...

           vintage.image.variations.medium   vintage.image.variations.medium_square  ...  \
0  //images.vivino.com/thumbs/M-DRD7hCQ...  //images.vivino.com/thumbs/M-DRD7hCQ...  ...

                          vintage.seo_name vintage.statistics.labels_count vintage.statistics.ratings_average  \
0  kvareli-akhasheni-red-akhasheni-kras...                             409                                4.6

   vintage.statistics.ratings_count  vintage.statistics.status
0                                37                     Normal

[1 rows x 12 columns]
```

первая строка:

```
In [45]: df.loc[0]
Out[45]:
vintage.id                                                              156240236
vintage.image.location                    //images.vivino.com/labels/M-DRD7hCQ...
vintage.image.variations.large            //images.vivino.com/thumbs/M-DRD7hCQ...
vintage.image.variations.medium           //images.vivino.com/thumbs/M-DRD7hCQ...
vintage.image.variations.medium_square    //images.vivino.com/thumbs/M-DRD7hCQ...
vintage.image.variations.small_square     //images.vivino.com/thumbs/M-DRD7hCQ...
vintage.name                              Kvareli Akhasheni Red (Ахашени Красн...
vintage.seo_name                          kvareli-akhasheni-red-akhasheni-kras...
vintage.statistics.labels_count                                               409
vintage.statistics.ratings_average                                            4.6
vintage.statistics.ratings_count                                               37
vintage.statistics.status                                                  Normal
```

---

можно отфильтровать все столбцы связанные с `image`:

```
In [46]: cols = df.columns[~df.columns.str.contains("image")]

In [47]: df[cols]
Out[47]:
   vintage.id                             vintage.name                         vintage.seo_name  \
0   156240236  Kvareli Akhasheni Red (Ахашени Красн...  kvareli-akhasheni-red-akhasheni-kras...

   vintage.statistics.labels_count  vintage.statistics.ratings_average  vintage.statistics.ratings_count  \
0                              409                                 4.6                                37

  vintage.statistics.status
0                    Normal

In [48]: df[cols].loc[0]
Out[48]:
vintage.id                                                          156240236
vintage.name                          Kvareli Akhasheni Red (Ахашени Красн...
vintage.seo_name                      kvareli-akhasheni-red-akhasheni-kras...
vintage.statistics.labels_count                                           409
vintage.statistics.ratings_average                                        4.6
vintage.statistics.ratings_count                                           37
vintage.statistics.status                                              Normal
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Для вашего случая:

```
import json

data = json.loads("""{
  "explore_vintage": {
    "market": {
      "country": "ru",
      "currency": {
        "code": "RUB",
        "name": "Russian Rouble",
        "prefix": null,
        "suffix": "₽"
      }
    },
    "records_matched": 9114,
    "matches": [
      {
        "vintage": {
          "id": 156240236,
          "seo_name": "kvareli-akhasheni-red-akhasheni-krasnoe-kakheti-2013",
          "name": "Kvareli Akhasheni Red (Ахашени Красное) 2013",
          "statistics": {
            "status": "Normal",
            "ratings_count": 37,
            "ratings_average": 4.6,
            "labels_count": 409
          },
          "image": {
            "location": "//images.vivino.com/labels/M-DRD7hCQfK60EBrmnbXYA.jpg",
            "variations": {
              "large": "//images.vivino.com/thumbs/M-DRD7hCQfK60EBrmnbXYA_375x500.jpg",
              "medium": "//images.vivino.com/thumbs/M-DRD7hCQfK60EBrmnbXYA_150x200.jpg",
              "medium_square": "//images.vivino.com/thumbs/M-DRD7hCQfK60EBrmnbXYA_150x150.jpg",
              "small_square": "//images.vivino.com/thumbs/M-DRD7hCQfK60EBrmnbXYA_80x80.jpg"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}""")

print(*[i['vintage']['name'] for i in data['explore_vintage']['matches']])
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, Антон. А если мне еще необходимо вытащить 'ratings_average'. Как провалиться на еще 1 уровень вложенности?

Comment: По аналогии с `i['vintage']['name']`. `i['vintage']['statistics']['ratings_average']`